# Regular Expression for a specific ID in a bracket

Tags: php, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have little confidence when it comes to regular expressions. Writing this in PHP code.

I need to be able to filter out strings that follow this format, where the numbers can be 4~6 digits (numeric only):

```
$input = "This is my string with a weird ID added cause I'm a weirdo! (id:11223)";
```

I could simply remove the last word by finding the last position of a space via `strrpos();` (it appears none of them have a trailing space from JSON feed), then use `substr();` to cut it. But I think the more elegant way would be a substring. The intended output would be:

```
$output = trim(preg_replace('[regex]', $input));
// $output = "This is my string with a weird ID added cause I'm a weirdo!"
```

So this regex should match with the brackets, and the id: portion, and any contiguous numbers, such as:

```
(id:33585)
(id:1282)
(id:9845672)
```

Intending to use the `preg_replace()` function to remove these from a data feed. Don't ask me why they decided to include an ID in the description string... It blows my mind too why it's not a separate column in the JSON feed altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the pattern `\(id:\d+\)`:

```
$input = "Text goes here (id:11223) and also here (id:33585) blah blah";
echo $input . "\n";
$output = preg_replace("/\(id:\d+\)/", "", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
Text goes here (id:11223) and also here (id:33585) blah blah
Text goes here  and also here  blah blah
```

There is an edge case here, which you can see in the possible (unwanted) extract whitespace left behind after the replacement.  We could try to get sophisticated and remove that too, but you should state what you expected output is.

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions and there is no attempts or [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this question

Comment: @Andreas It gets philosophical here.  The OP's question was, in my opinion, well-written.  That it doesn't contain any PHP code, by itself, in my mind, does not disqualify it, assuming the OP might not know PHP's regex API very well.  I mean, had the OP included some broken code, would that have really helped the question?  It might have made it worse.

Comment: It's not philosophical at all. OP's question simply didn't show what has been attempted so far, which doesn't make it a well-asked question (since showing attempts has been one of the main guidelines on this site).

Comment: I know how the preg_replace function with provided regex. This is all I needed, also was open to any other ideas in case somebody had it. I didn't attempt anything because I knew exactly what I wa lacking - enough knowledge for regex syntaxes and the exceptions. I know exactly how to implement it.

Comment: Got a warning: 
Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found in ...

I now have preg_replace("/\(id:\d+\)/", $input); and it works beautifully!

Comment: @Andreas I thought removing the PHP stuff would make the final objective (focus on targeted string) but I added the PHP code anyway. Looking better?

Comment: Nope, not at all, since the most important thing is not your PHP code. The main part of your question is regex, rather than PHP. Therefore, you should post what kind of regex has you tried so far and how is it not working.